# How to avoid duplicate records with user edits in a referential system?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

PostgreSQL 10.1

I am curious to see how the SO Community deals with this common database problem.

The problem is this. I have textual descriptions of various problems being entered at the desktop into the table ICD_Descriptions (the middle box below). Generally speaking there will also be one code associated with each description. However, over time (i.e., years), the codes for a specific text phrase/description will change. Hence, a general many-to-many relationship will exist for some codes to descriptions. So a third table, dx_log, is being used to allow for a many-to-many relationship between the code and the descriptions. Lastly, other "children" tables that need to see a specific combination of 'code-description' will be given a reference to the primary key (the recid) of the dx_log. I believe this arrangement to be fairly standard database management.

O.K., now for the problem. I wish the codes in the icd_code table to be unique to that table. I also wish the descriptions in the icd_description table to be unique to their table.

The problem. This being a referential system, changes to either the "data" part of the code table, (the code), or the description (in the descriptions table) will be seen in the child tables.

But, **how to correctly manage user edits to a code or description that would conflict with the "unique" rule of the respective table**?

As an example, lets say the initial text of a description is "this is mispelled", whereas another description text has "this is misspelled". At one point it time, both phrases coexist and are unique. However, at a later point in time, the wrong record is corrected (i.e., mispelled --->misspelled). When the edits are attempted to be saved to the file, it will be detected that the correct record already exists.

So if the dx_log table is also unique on (icd_description_recid, icd_code_recid), then **simply replacing the reference to the already existing correctly spelled record in the dx_log will lead to a violation of uniqueness for the dx_log table.** Therefore, I can think of only three solutions:

1. The table which the children tables actually reference **CAN NOT HAVE A UNIQUES** constraint on its reference pointers,
2. Leave the uniqueness constraint on the dx_log, but when a conflict would violate uniqueness, then use a migrate procedure to **move the child table references** to the existing record (in postgresql this would be heavy use of the catalogs) to the "new record", then delete the existing record before adding the new record.
3. Add an additional self-reference pointer in the dx_log such that when a record would conflict with an already existing record in dx_log, then don't change it but rather **place a pointer to the already existing "correct" record** in the dx_log.

I hope I've explained my question well enough. What is the recommended approach?

Thanks for any comments.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the 2. is the correct solution.

Yes, that requires that all dependent records in `dx_log` have to be updated when two entries are consolidated, but you have an index on `dx_log(icd_description_recid)` anyway, right?

The other solutions compromise data consistency and will make all queries on the system more complicated and probably slower.

Comment: @ LaurenzAlbe This is what I am currently doing, but since I may not know ahaed of time the child tables that need to be updated, I needed to use the Postgresql catalogs to find all the tables referencing the dx_log. While great for postgresql, I wonder how this approach would be used for other databases, e.g SQL, ???  Or if there was a better way with PostgreSQL 10.1 now out??

Comment: This is what I am doing currently, But since I don't know ahead of time what tables will be dependent on the dx_log, I am forced to use the PostgreSQL catalogs to find the tables referencing the dx_log. So I'm wondering if PostgreSQL has a "more up to date" approach and what approach other databases (e.g., MySQL) would take. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to know the tables with a foreign key reference to `dx_log` to change aan attribute that is not the referenced key?

Comment: My set up might be wrong. The primary key for all my tables is the recid (serial) of each table. The children tables -- now and in the future--all reference the recid of dx_log. Not allowing duplicate records in dx_log on (icd_code_recid, icd_description_recid) means that if either the icd_code or icd_description tables would have an entry that already exists, then this would imply that a duplicate record will have to exist in the dx_log table. The tables referencing the dx_log would NOT have to be changed if duplicates in the dx_log are allowed.

Comment: I had missed the uniqueness constraint on `(icd_code_recid, icd_description_recid)`. True, then such a change would require reparenting of all orphaned dependent rows in other tables. I guess you'll have to assess how painful that is. It would be the cleanest solution, but if you cannot pay the price, you'll have to settle for less.

Answer (score 1):

4. Separate the idea of a natural unique constraint from the idea of a key.  Use a system generated surrogate key for referential integrity, and a UNIQUE INDEX for the natural key.   Then you don't have to reparent anything.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "natural key", nor how it doesn't change where the problem occurs when two indexes collide?

Comment: natural key is related to the data itself.   something like UNIQUE (prefix,firstname,lastname,suffix).   surrogate key is unrelated (id bigserial primary key).    They should never collide.